# Mapping does not work in short style (.map(&:id))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to perform this very simple RUBY map statement:

```
    result_apartments = [{:id=>"593363170", :title=>"Country House", :price=>{:cents=>30000000, :currency=>"EUR", :human=>"€300,000.00"}, :sqm=>130, :numberOfBedrooms=>30, :numberOfBathrooms=>1}, {:id=>"906270510", :title=>"City Flat", :price=>{:cents=>80000000, :currency=>"USD", :human=>"$800,000.00"}, :sqm=>60, :numberOfBedrooms=>5, :numberOfBathrooms=>23}]


puts result_apartments.map(&:id)
```

Somehow it throws the error: `map': undefined method id' for #<Hash:0x0055d52`

**What is the issue here? What is wrong in the array presentation? And how should I change it so that I can map it in this short cut version: `map(&:id)`**

Somehow (map{|a| a[:id]}) works!

Comment: The error is very clear. The hash does not respond to an `id` method. It has an `id` key. `map(&:id)` is equivalent to `map{|a| a.id}` not `map{|a| a[:id]}`.

Comment: _"how should I change it"_ – replace the general purpose container (`Hash`) with a specialized class (`Apartment`) that provides methods for `id`, `title`, `price` etc.

Comment: Might be worth noting that calling `map { |a| a[:id] }` on the hash is certainly much faster than translating it into another data structure (like a dedicated class or an OpenStruct) first and then iterating all records with `map(&:id)`.

Comment: Not short but oneline: `result_apartments.map(&->(x){x[:id]})`

Comment: @vovan a casual `map { |x| x[:id] }` is even shorter – there's no need (or benefit) to wrap the block in a lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short method is attempting to call a method `id` on each hash.  That's not a hash method.  If you do...

```
result_apartments.first.id
```

You'll see that `id` isn't a valid method.

Instead of hashes you could have an array of OpenStruct

```
require 'ostruct'

structured_result_apartments = result_paraments.map { |hash| OpenStruct.new hash }
```

Then you can do

```
structured_result_apartments.map(&:id)
```